# What do you call an arched entrance to a garden?

Tags: word-request

[image: entrance]

What do you call an arched entrance to a garden? I am not sure if there's a word specifically for garden entrances, but I am willing to bet there's a word for an arched entrance like that. What do you call it?

Comment: I'd just call it a "fence gate". Maybe "a fence gate under an arch".

Comment: Eddie's answer may be correct for the US, but I (BrE) would call it a garden gate with an arch. You may find this reference useful for garden terms: https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/ep432

Comment: You could refer to it as a lych gate, but this term is mainly used for the entrance to a churchyard, and normally has a waterproof roof. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychgate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call it an [archway](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/archway), or *An arch over an entrance or passageway* but those can vary a lot in size and materials. If you are speaking very specifically about an arched entry into a garden, I would call it a [garden arch](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/garden+arch) or an [arbor](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/arbour).

Arbor was the first thing I thought of, but in my mind, it is always meant to be covered in some sort of climbing plant, and it’s not always over a passageway. Arbors can be set over a bench to provide a nice shady place to sit.

Like most words in English, the choice of which one works best depends on the context.